# Selecting only numbers from a string

Tags: sql

We have a program that can pull information from a database that we use for shipping.  The way it works is it uses an ODBC driver to pull from our database, so that when we type in "order number 5" into the shipping program it will also pull the matching address, phone number, etc.

The problem is that the database contains only numbers for the orders, however the program that contains the database which we use for inventory management prints our labels with the order number in the format TK123456.  I need to figure out how to make SQL interpret the order number as just numbers when inputted, so basically cut the TK off the start.

```
SELECT RXFILL.RXFILL_ID, RXMAIN.RX_NUMBER, PATIENT.FIRSTNAME, PATIENT.LASTNAME,
     SHIPADDRESS1, SHIPADDRESS2, SHIPCITY, SHIPSTATE, SHIPZIP, EMAIL
 FROM RXFILL 
 LEFT JOIN RXMAIN ON RXFILL.RXMAIN_ID = RXMAIN.RXMAIN_ID
 LEFT JOIN PATIENT ON RXMAIN.PATIENT_ID = PATIENT.PATIENT_ID
 WHERE RXFILL_ID=$ORDERNUMBER
```

If I am understanding it correctly the $ORDERNUMBER is what needs to be adjusted to not include letters.  However the program does specify the final line must be in the format `WHERE [field name]=$ORDERNUMBER`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want this to be solved in SQL and not in the calling application, and you know that the first two characters of $ORDERNUMBER will always be 'TK', then you can easily solve it by taking a substring of $ORDERNUMBER starting at the third character... i.e.

```
WHERE RXFILL_ID=SUBSTRING($ORDERNUMBER, 2).
```

That syntax might not be exact, since you haven't divulged your DBMS type and each DBMS implements SUBSTRING in whatever way they want.

If you share more info about the calling application which sets $ORDERNUMBER, I'm sure it would be better to make the change there.

Comment: Just as a note, the question did not specify the database.  In some databases, the function is SUBSTR() and in some databases it requires a third argument (so SUBSTR(xxx, xxx, 1000) would work).

Answer (score 0):

I have write a function for this.

```
CREATE Function SelectNumbersFromString(@str varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max) as 
BEGIN

Declare @cchk char(5);
Declare @len  int ;
Declare @aschr int;

SET @len = ( SElect len(@str) );
Declare @count int
SET @count = 1

DECLARE @ans varchar(max)
SET @ans = ''

While @count <= @len
BEGIN
    SET @cchk = ( select Substring(@str,@count,1) );    
    SET @aschr = ( select ASCII(@cchk) );
    IF  @aschr in ( 49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58 )
    BEGIN   
        SET @ans = @ans + CHAR(@aschr)          
    END 
    SET @count = @count + 1;
END

RETURN @ans;
END
```

**TESTED**
`SELECT SelectNumbersFromString('abc3deef5ff6') will return 356`

From  http://wfjanjua.blogspot.com/2012/07/add-numbers-from-stringvarchar-in-tsql.html